# document.documentElement function does not display proper result

Tags: javascript, xml

I am trying to parse XML file using java-script. According to the tutorial I read I found That To get the Root element, I have to use `document.documentElement`.

I use that syntax but when I tried to display the returned value from that Syntax, the browser displays `[object HTMLHtmlElement]`.

My question is: (1) Why I am getting `[object HTMLHtmlElement]` displayed in the web browser.
                (2) According to the below posted XML-File, What should I expect the output to be 
                    after using`rootElement = document.documentElement;`

Please find below the code I used(Javascript) and the XML file.

**Javascript**

```
function findWriter() 
{
        var schriftstellerKnoten, SpracheKnoten;
        var FuellerKnoten, DichtungKnoten, Anzeige, rootElement;

    rootElement = document.documentElement;
    document.write(rootElement);     
    }
```

**XML file**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<Schriftsteller>
   <Englischsprache>
      <Dichtung> 
         <fueller>
        <name>Jane Austin</name>
            <name>Rex Stout</name>
            <name>Dashiell Hammett</name>    
     </fueller>
  </Dichtung>
   </Englischsprache>
</Schriftsteller>
```

Comment: Simply because you're getting an object (in this case, a node).

Comment: Have you tried to debug the Javascript snippet and check this object properties?

Comment: You are fetching the documentElement of your parent page (HTML) into the `rootElement` variable. Can you post the code of how you are getting the XML file? You must first fetch the XML file.

Comment: @Harry: I just want to know how to display the name in the name tag `Jane Austin`

Comment: @Harry: I just want to know how to display the name in the name tag `name>Jane Austin</name>`

Answer (score 2):

`document.documentElement` will get you the root HTML tag of the page in which your javascript is present.

To fetch and display the XML content, you must get access to the XML document and then use it to load the XML file like the following:

```
function findWriter() 
{
    var schriftstellerKnoten, SpracheKnoten;
    var FuellerKnoten, DichtungKnoten, Anzeige, rootElement;

  if (window.XMLHttpRequest){
    xhttp=new XMLHttpRequest(); //For non IE browsers
  }
  else { // for IE 5/6 
    xhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  xhttp.open("GET","test.xml",false);
  xhttp.send();
  xmlDoc=xhttp.responseXML; //Fetch the XML file contents

  var nameEl = xmlDoc.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("name"); //Get all <name> tags in it
  for (i=0; i<nameEl.length; i++){
    document.write("Name" + i + ": " + nameEl[i].firstChild.nodeValue + "<br/>"); //write names
  }
}
```

Comment: yes, i modified my code as you suggested but it does not work

Comment: what is the error? which browser & version? are you running the code on a server like tomcat? make sure you are.

Comment: the just does generate any result..i am using CHrome.

Comment: @AmrBakri: your server?